# Aws elb rule path in cloudwatch metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-elb

Hi all is there any way where i can get url path(listener rule) in aws elb cloudwatch metrics like we have matched_url_path_rule in gcp loadbalacing metrics.